# I'm having trouble coming up with the winning logic for Tic Tac Toe

Tags: javascript

I'm going through `The Odin Project` and I'm working on completing *Tic Tac Toe*. I have almost everything completed but I'm stuck with coming up with the logic that checks what symbol (X or O) is being stored in each board and how to check for a winner. The directions say to store everything inside an array so I was doing that but I can't figure out how to update the array to store whichever symbol and check for a winner.

***You’re going to store the gameboard as an array inside of a Gameboard object**, so start there! Your players are also going to be stored in objects… and you’re probably going to want an object to control the flow of the game itself.*

This is what I have completed so far.

I have a `player` function that stores each players name and the symbol that represents them.

```
const player = (name, symbol) => {
  return { name, symbol };
};

const Player1 = player("Player X", "X");
const Player2 = player("Player O", "O");
```

I have a for loop that loops through my main div and creates 9 divs that represent the 9 squares for the game.

```
const createGameBoard = function () {
  for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    gameBoardElements(); // Function that appends div to main board class
  }
};
createGameBoard();
```

This is the function I'm using when I click on one of the divs. At the top I have the variable `turn = 0` and after every click, it goes up by one. Using the modulus operator and my `player` function I'm making the text inside the board div either X or O and I'm changing the class so the div has a different background color. I know I could use the `style` feature but I don't like changing my html too much.

```
const board = document.querySelectorAll(".game-board");
board.forEach((el) => el.addEventListener("click", selectBoard));

// Decides which symbol to add to board: X or O
function selectBoard(e) {
  e.target.appendChild(
    createPElement(`${turn % 2 === 0 ? Player1.symbol : Player2.symbol}`)
  );
  turn++;
  e.target.className = "complete-board";
  e.target.removeEventListener("click", selectBoard); // prevent additional clicks
}
```

**What I've tried**

I've tried creating the array `myGameBoard` and appending each div to it inside the `createGameBoard` function

```
let myGameBoard = [
  {board: 1, value: ""}
  {board: 2, value: ""}
  etc...
];
```

But I couldn't find a way to update the `value` of each div after I click to make it either an X or an O.

```js
const currentTurn = document.getElementById("current-turn");
const getGameBoard = document.getElementById("board");
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");

let turn = 0;

// Main Player function. Gives default name and symbol
const player = (name, symbol) => {
  return { name, symbol };
};

const Player1 = player("Player X", "X");
const Player2 = player("Player O", "O");
console.log(Player1);

// Creates a div and appends to board div
const gameBoardElements = function () {
  const getBoard = document.getElementById("board");
  const createBoard = document.createElement("div");
  getBoard.appendChild(createBoard);
  createBoard.className = "game-board";
};

// For loop that creates 9 divs and adds to board div
const createGameBoard = function () {
  for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    gameBoardElements(); // Function that appends div to main board class
  }
};
createGameBoard();

// Creates the [p] element that displays either X or O inside the gameboard div
function createPElement(symbol) {
  let p = document.createElement("p");
  p.textContent = symbol;
  p.className = "text";
  return p;
}

// Selects all game boards and assigns two event listener functions
const board = document.querySelectorAll(".game-board");
board.forEach((el) => el.addEventListener("click", selectBoard));
board.forEach((el) => el.addEventListener("click", updateBoard));

// Decides which symbol to add to board: X or O
function selectBoard(e) {
  e.target.appendChild(
    createPElement(`${turn % 2 === 0 ? Player1.symbol : Player2.symbol}`)
  );
  turn++;
  e.target.className = "complete-board";
  e.target.removeEventListener("click", selectBoard); // prevent additional clicks
}

// Updates the [p] tag that shows whose turn it is at the top
function updateBoard() {
  currentTurn.textContent = `${
    turn % 2 === 0 ? `${Player1.name} turn` : `${Player2.name} turn`
  }`;
}

// Reset button text display
btn.addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
  this.textContent = "Reset >>";
});
btn.addEventListener("mouseout", function () {
  this.textContent = "Reset >";
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #fffdfa;
}

.title {
  font-size: 42px;
  font-family: "Dancing Script", cursive;
}

.current-turn {
  font-size: 24px;
}

.content {
  background-color: #fffdfa;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 700px;
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.board {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  gap: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 500px;
  width: 600px;
}

.board div,
.complete-board {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  background-color: #3c4048;
  width: 175px;
  height: 150px;
}

.board div:hover {
  background-color: #f4e06d;
  transform: scale(1.1);
  transition: 0.8s;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.complete-board {
  background-color: #f4e06d !important;
}

.text {
  font-size: 64px;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #4649ff;
  padding: 0.5em 2em;
  margin-top: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: "Poor Story", cursive;
  font-size: 2rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.4rem;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn:hover {
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.parallelogram {
  transform: skew(-20deg);
}

.skew-fix {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: skew(20deg);
}
```

```html
    <div class="content">
      <p class="title">Tic Tac Toe</p>
      <p class="current-turn" id="current-turn">Player X Turn</p>
      <div id="board" class="board"></div>
      <a id="btn" class="btn parallelogram" onclick="reset()">
        <span class="skew-fix">Reset ></span>
      </a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The winning logic will include checking the element if

- it is any one of the corner elements or if it is the element at the center.
- it is any of the other elements.

If it is case 1, you will check all horizontal/vertical/diagonal elements if they are the same.

If it is case 2, you will check for all horizontal/vertical elements if they are the same.

If any of the above two statements are true, then you have won the game.

I hope I gave you some hint or logic.